# why 1 is subtracted from mod where mod =1000000007 in calculation

Tags: math, numbers, primes, number-theory, modulo

link of question

http://codeforces.com/contest/615/problem/D
link of solution is
http://codeforces.com/contest/615/submission/15260890

In below code i am not able to understand why 1 is subtracted from mod
where mod=1000000007

```
ll d = 1;
ll ans = 1;
for (auto x : cnt) {
    ll cnt = x.se;
    ll p = x.fi;
    ll fp = binPow(p, (cnt + 1) * cnt / 2, MOD);
    ans = binPow(ans, (cnt + 1), MOD) * binPow(fp, d, MOD) % MOD;
    d = d * (x.se + 1) % (MOD - 1);//why ??
}
```

Comment: No one else is terribly likely to know either, since you haven't indicated what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: now, i add the link of solution and problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that there is the code does not make much sense as out of context as it is, there is the **little theorem of Fermat**:

Whenever `MOD` is a prime number, as `10^9+7` is, one can reduce exponents by multiples of `(MOD-1)` as for any `a` not a multiple of `MOD`

```
a ^ (MOD-1) == 1  mod MOD.
```

Which means that

```
a^b == a ^ (b mod (MOD-1))  mod MOD.
```

---

As to the code, which is efficient for its task, consider `n=m*p^e` where `m` is composed of primes smaller than `p`.

Then for each factor `f` of `m` there are factors `1*f, p*f, p^2*f,...,p^e*f` of `n`. The product over all factors of `n` thus is the product over

```
p^(0+1+2+...+e) * f^(e+1) = p^( e*(e+1)/2 ) * f^(e+1)
```

over all factors `f` of `m`. Putting the numbers of factors as `d` and the product of factors of `m` as `ans` results in the combined formula

```
ans = ans^( e+1 ) * p^( d*e*(e+1)/2 )
d = d*(e+1)
```

which can now be recursively applied to the list of prime factors and their multiplicities.